# How to access a digital products information on the products page in Craft Commerce?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, plugin-digitalproducts

I have created a digital product type and a digital product but strangely on the digital products template I can't access any information regarding the product like for example, entry.title. I'm getting a `Variable "entry" does not exist.` error. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `entry` use `product` variable. For example, `{{product.title}}`.